# How to stop ajax after success resp

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-5

I have run ajax on page load. I want to stop ajax after success response.
and i am using Laravel Framework. Can anyone help me out to this Poblem.Here is my code:-

```
enter code here
$(document).ready(function(){

function images(){
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'CheckImageCount',
        success:function(resp){
            if($.trim(resp)=="empty"){
                $('.error-1').show();
                $('.error-2').hide();
                $("#CheckImageCount").prop('disabled', true);
                return false;
            }
            else if($.trim(resp)=="error"){
                $('.error-1').hide();
                $('.error-2').fadeIn('fast').show();
                $("#CheckImageCount").prop('disabled', true);
                return false;
            }
            else{
                console.log(resp); //it will print suucess
                $("#CheckImageCount").prop('disabled', false);
            }
        },
        error:function(){
        }
    })
}
window.setInterval(function()
        {
            images();
        }, 1000); 
});
```

And here is my Function in laravel

```
public function CheckImageCount(Request $request){
    $images = $request->session()->get('businessimages');
    if(empty($images)){
        echo "empty";die;
    }
    elseif(count($images) < 5){
        echo "error";die;
    }
    else{
        echo "success";die;
    }
}
```

Comment: write you images() function outside the `$(document).ready()`

Comment: @RimonKhan PO don't want to stop calling function on page load he want to stop function after successful response

Comment: it will working fine but i want to stop ajax after success resp

Comment: Don't use `setInterval` and call `images()` inside success callback with `if` statment and `setTimeout()` as you like.

Comment: @Mamdoh Can you write code